# Can I connect to local server on expo application without ngrok or localtunnel?

Tags: server, expo, fetch

[image]

I want to connect to the server on expo application using fetch API. So I've searched about it, but many post said the solution is using `ngrok` or `localtunnel` to host it.

But I want to connect without hosting server online. Is it possible?

Thank you.
Please excuse my poor English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you are running a server on `http://localhost:3000` on your PC and you are using the Expo GO application on your simulator.

Then, you can do the following to get the correct URL of the sever `Platform.OS === "android" ? "http://10.0.2.2:3000" : "http://localhost:3000"`

However, if you are running Expo GO on a physical device (iOS or Android), you will have to use `ngrok`. [Here is](https://dsinecos.github.io/blog/How-to-call-a-locally-hosted-server-from-expo-app) simple blog tutorial showing you how this is possible.